# Why are some of the links on ELL not styled according to the color swatch in our design?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was reading over [a question on EL&U's meta site about a graphical problem](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9346/80039) and when I looked at their [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) I noticed it incorporated the colors and fonts of their main site, while our [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) still has the styling of the beta site (with the exception of the background image). After thinking about it some more and looking at the other pages in the site I think it caught my attention for two reasons:

1. The help center is mostly links, and "unvisited" link color is the default blue and not a color from our swatch.
2. The headings on the sections are black instead of the cyan or gray in our swatch.
3. The unvisited links here on Meta are all orange, and the visited links are a darker red. I had the meta tab open at the same time I was poking around trying to figure out why the look of the help site seemed off, and it made the difference of the default blue links more obvious.

Is this intentional? I realize it isn't that big a deal, but I'm a little bit jealous of the cohesiveness of the other SE sites that have their themes throughout.

If we're going to have cyan headers and orange visited links, we shouldn't have default blue for unvisited links. It looks like someone forgot something. Here is the color swatch from the site design and that default blue link color is nowhere to be found in it:

[image: ELL Color swatch]

[image: ELU Main]
[image: ELU Help]
[image: ELL Main]
[image: ELL Help]

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting old because I don't see any differences except bgcolor. q_q

Comment: Can you be *really specific* about what the perceived problem is? because it looks right to me; can you please call out exactly what you think should be another  colour (and: which colour you expect it to be...). Regular links (not  post  titles etc) are blue on *many many* pages on ell

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess that is what caught my attention. On EL&U the links follow the coloring of the body and headings and on ELL they links are the same old default blue instead of the cyan. The text of the help center looks exactly the same as it did when we were in beta to me and I just never noticed it until I paid attention to what EL&U's help center looked like. Shouldn't the headings at least be cyan? If you look at our color swatch, that default blue isn't anywhere in it and it seems like an omission to me.

Comment: @ColleenV again, though, what you describe is not unique to the help centre - there are blue links on pretty much every page; the only distinguishing feature about  the help centre is that  it has more links in a block than most...

Comment: @MarcGravell I've updated the question to (I hope) make it more clear. You're correct that the help center jumped out at me because of the number of links on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be jealous no longer:

> [image: ELL help center links, which are teal]
>
> [image: ELL blog/meta posts sidebar, as seen from the main site with teal links]

Ah, cohesion.

Comment: I had totally forgotten about this! How did you end up noticing there was a fix?

Comment: @ColleenV It was on the unanswered meta questions list. BOOM free meta rep 